# Setka - Complete grid using clues and sudoku-style logic

Tags: logical-deduction, word, wordplay

This is a Setka puzzle; you can find more (along with a more detailed explanation of the rules) at our website, linked from this user's profile.

How to play Setka, the short version:

Answer each clue using only Puzzle Letters and vowels.

Clue answers, minus vowels and duplicate letters, go in the corresponding boxes in the grid. Only Puzzle Letters go in the grid!

Puzzle Letters can be entered forward/backward/up/down/L-shape, but not jumbled. They also cannot repeat in a row or column.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Puzzling! It looks as if part of your reason for posting here may be to promote your website; you should have a look at our guidelines on [How Not To Be A Spammer](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4340/how-not-to-be-a-spammer-redux) to avoid suspicion of self-interested self-promotion. I've put a link to your website into your profile, and I'll edit the question to make it suitably non-self-promoting.

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, you're _absolutely welcome_ to be here and to post puzzles from your website, just so long as you do it in a way designed to benefit the community here rather than using PSE as an advertising platform. This looks like it may be an interesting new type of puzzle; thanks for introducing us to it!

Comment: Thanks Gareth! I will review the guidelines and do my best to follow them.

Comment: @setkagames, Is it possible to add a new rule: letters cannot repeat in diagonals.

Comment: Great question! Just like sudoku, the letters can't repeat in a row or column, but sometimes they might repeat in a diagonal. Really hope you enjoyed the puzzle!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To solve the board after solving each clues, put first the 1-letter-puzzle and the second letter of 3-letter-puzzle. And this will be the full solution:

> [image]

Comment: Nice job! Hope you enjoyed the puzzle. We will continue posting them.